# Show all items in youtube library menu

Tags: javascript, youtube, tampermonkey

New youtube broke my tampermonkey script which would show all my playlists in the left menu.

```
document.getElementsByClassName("yt-uix-expander-collapsed")[0].classList.remove("yt-uix-expander-collapsed");
```

Because the content isn't hidden anymore, I can't figure out how to get it working again, any ideas?

Comment: Since the content is no longer hidden, and no longer able to be collapsed, what are you expecting the script to do?

Comment: I want to change it so that it works again but I can't figure out how youtube does this now. I guess I need to find out which function is executed to execute it in my script.